# If a number have same number get_avatar

Tags: php, wordpress, get

This is working code that gets the data from a field that registered users have to fill out in their profiles in wordpress:

```
<?php 
    $field = xprofile_get_field_data(2, $user_id); 
    echo '<span class="wisfb_carNumber">' . $field . '<span>';
?>
```

This is the code that generates data from a Excel-file:

```
<?php $data = wp_excel_cms_get("EXCEL-DOCUMENT"); ?>

<?php foreach($data as $entry): ?> 

    <?php echo $entry[1]; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now I want to do this:

**If the number witch is generated in `<?php echo $entry[1]; ?>` is the same number as in the users `$field = xprofile_get_field_data(2, $user_id);` get this users avatar.**

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Wild guess at what you are trying to do: `<?php echo $entry[$field]; ?>`

Comment: @mkaatman no, not matching up:  
I want this `<?php echo $entry[1]`  to match `$field = xprofile_get_field_data(2, $user_id);` then `echo get_avatar();  ?>` to get the match and avatar result...